# Regarding Remote SMTP

Tags: smtp

I am trying to send mail using remote Gmail SMTP from my joomla website.
Do I still need to install & configure MTA such such postfix for connecting to remote Gmail Servers or the joomla would take care itself and connect to GMail SMTP Server?  I have already entered the details provided by google for setting up SMTP in joomla backend.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need an MTA if you are directly connecting to Gmail SMTP, if you did this and the MTA dealt with Gmail you would need to change config. to point to the MTA.